# Apache & Nginx (each as reverse proxy) having very different behavior for self signed backend certificate

Tags: java, apache, nginx, webserver, reverse-proxy

I am deploying Angular on Nginx & Apache http server (as reverse proxy web servers) in my UAT environment with the backend being on spring boot on Apache Tomcat (encrypted with https for the java REST apis), I have noticed that Nginx was configured as reverse proxy much easier than Apache BUT that was largely because Apache didn't trust the Java APIs certificate (as it is self signed, so this seems correct)

Can someone explain why this happened? I trust that Nginx is secure but I want to know why it allowed this self signed certificate while Apache by default blocked it (only allowed it with SSLProxyVerify none)?

Nginx config (related part):

```
    location /api {
    proxy_pass  https://192.168.170.78:7002/;
    }
```

Apache config (the related part):

```
# SSL proxy config
SSLProxyEngine on

# Why this must be present for the apache to connect to the backend but not for nginx?
SSLProxyCheckPeerName off

# the (proxy) redirection rules for the server
ProxyPass /api/ https://192.168.170.78:7002/
ProxyPassReverse /api/ https://192.168.170.78:7002/
```

Comment: `nginx` can check your upstream certificates. But you will need to turn it on. See [this link](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate) for more.

Comment: Thanks Richard, so by default Apache check proxy certificate but Nginx doesn't, is that dangerous? or it is just Nginx assumes the admin knows what he is doing & is proxying to a trusted server?